How are signed tags created through the Bitbucket Datacenter REST api?
I am trying to do some automated housekeeping with bitbucket. So far the REST API has not posed much of a challenge. However, I'm stuck at an API call that is not well documented and I'm unsure how to proceed.
I would like to create a tag through this API endpoint:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v903/api-group-repository/#api-git-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-tags-post
If I do this, I am rightfully reprimanded by the Server:
Signed commits and tags are enforced for this repository.

However, the documentation does not seem to cover how to sign the tag through the API. Using a full git client, cloning repos, etc. is not an option for the volume of operations we would like to perform.
Has anyone solved this already?
